# Unable to write to folder after mounted as read/write

Tags: permissions, mount, virtualbox, fstab

I have 2 folders in Windows: data1 and data2, both belong to me and I have full control of them. I've added them to the shared folder list in Virtualbox and mount them as readwrite in /etc/fstab

```
data1         /home/user/samba/data1         vboxsf  rw,uid=1234,gid=1234
data2         /home/user/samba/data2         vboxsf  rw,uid=1234,gid=1234
```

However the strange thing is that when I list the folders one is not writable so I can't put data inside it

```
dr-xr-xr-x  8 user user 4.0K Oct 13 03:05 data1/
drwxrwxrwx  8 user user 4.0K Oct 13 03:05 data2/
```

To be precise, only the **root of data1** is unwritable, it's internal directories are still writable. The whole tree of data2 is writable

My user is already in vboxsf group and I also have normal write permission in the other mounted folder.

I was trying all that I can think of including `chmod` to add write permission to the folder before mounting but still no luck. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Try to open the properties of these folders in your Windows system and check if there are any differences.

Comment: *nix can't open a folder in read-write if the server they're on only provides only read permissions  (in which case it'll only show as read like you've got).  I'd check your server too.

Comment: @chrisguiver the host shared those folders with full permission. I can write in it normally from Windows or in Ubuntu with `sudo`

Comment: @M.Dm. there are no differences. The problem is in Ubuntu because `touch a` won't work but `sudo touch a` will work

Comment: are they hosted on different machines/hardware; different versions of samba(cifs/smb/..) used with resulting varying permissions (permissions in share config/protocols, which may not be visible from user level gui on windows).   windoze clients ignore permissions (ie. let user discover a write-permission-denied then complain) where as ubuntu will respect what it's told by server (not giving user the change to attempt write). i still think its a server issue.

Comment: no, the 2 folders are in the same host PC. Obviously it doesn't use samba because I use vboxsf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this adding `dmode` to the mount options for the affected folder

```
data1    /home/user/samba/data1    vboxsf  rw,uid=1234,gid=1234,dmask=000,dmode=777
```

Still not clear why it happens when all things being equal